# access files of app and run-as command alternative for debugging

Tags: applications, adb, root-access, storage, debug

I try to access `data\data` folder without root because I want to access some downloaded files by the app and I have realized the files download in data directory. I have tried to `pull` to sdcard but as in the picture it is not debuggable. So now, what can be done? Isn't there any way to access the files or grab the files without root privileges?

[image]